# Django: Delete or empty content of a row in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-filter

I'm looking to delete or empty a specific row in my table/model in my UpdateView. I have a team and employees in the team. I have made an update view that when "yes" is pressed, the team becomes archived. I want to additionally delete or empty the employee's numbers when doing so. How would I approach that?

I know it might be weird, but the idea is that the employee's numbers should be destroyed once the team is archived, while the rest of the data still stands.

**Team Model**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    teamname = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Indtast holdnavn.", null=False, primary_key=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**Employee Model**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    emp_num = models.IntegerField(help_text="Indtast medarbejderens MA-nummer. (F.eks 123456)")
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens fornavn.")
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens efternavn.")
    teamname = models.ForeignKey('Hold', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**UpdateView**

My updateView is using team, as its that model I'm updating.

```
class ArchiveHoldView(UpdateView):
        template_name = 'evalsys/medarbejder/archive_hold.html'
        model = Team
        form_class = ArchiveForm

        def archive_view_team_with_pk(self, slug=None):
            if slug:
                team = Team.objects.get(slug=slug)
            else:
                team = self.team
            args = {'team': team}
            return render(self, 'evalsys/medarbejder/archive_hold.html', args)

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ArchiveHoldView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['is_active'] = Team.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
            return context

        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse_lazy("evalsys:home")
```

**Update View form**

```
class ArchiveForm(forms.ModelForm):
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.instance.is_active = False
    return super(ArchiveForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

is_active = BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

class Meta:
    model = Team
    fields = ['is_active', ]
    labels = {'is_active': 'Is Active'}
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't see in your code where you're archiving the team. Also your `emp_num` cannot be empty because you didn't set `null=True` on it. So either set it to 0 (if you're happy with 0 meaning empty) or enable `null=True`. I don't really understand what's the problem you're facing, looping through all employees in a team, setting the number to `None` or `0` and saving it isn't particularly difficult or am I missing something?

Comment: Forgot the form view, thats where I change the boolean value on submit.

Comment: Added to the post.

Comment: Did not think about setting the values to None or 0, only thought about trying to delete the values. Not sure how to filter it and set it to None or 0 though.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't answer the second part of my comment. What is the exact issue you're facing? Why don't you loop through the employees of the team? What do you mean you don't know how to set it to 0? If you have an `employee`, `employee.emp_num = 0` sets it to 0.

Comment: I can loop through them, but I don't know how to target the emp_num? and the issues is I don't understand where to put the logic - in the context? The only success I've had is deleting all employees for a team.

Comment: There’s multiple options. You can do it in your form’s save method after calling `super().save()` or you can do it in the Team model’s `save` method or `post_save` signal handler. If you want to make sure the numbers are removed in all circumstances that the team is deactivated (also if this is done in the future in another view or form) then put it in the Team model.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks..but I can't figure out how to filter into the emp_num based on the Team model. I tried some different queries, like this:
`Employee.objects.filter(emp_num=self.kwargs.get('slug'))` but I get the error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'LBU20' - I've also change so emp_num can be null.

Comment: `team.employee_set.update(emp_num=0)` will update all employee of the team. I don't understand why you're filtering on emp_num.